# Problems with PyDev & Eclipse Juno on osX10.8

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osx-mountain-lion, pydev

I have had this problems for a couple of times but usually could solve it by an update. However, this fix does not work for me anymore.

Actually, two problems here:

1. The minor one: I have osX 10.8.3 and Eclipse Juno (M20130204-1200) installed. Since a good amount of time, it takes eclipse ~ 4-5 minutes to start up for the first time after the system start. Once it was closed and is re-opend again, it starts up quick. I think this problem came since apple started to mess around with the JRE? Does anybody also experienced this delay? Could it be that one of the installed plugins checks for updates and causes the delay?
2. The major one: after eclipse is fully up & running, I can not open .py files anymore. When I open my pydev project (btw. pydev 2.7.3), eclipse freezes and I need to kill the whole thing and restart. -> I can not use it for python coding anymore, which is my primary task... 
   Suggestions? Re-install eclipse maybe?

Thank you for suggestions,
El

Answer (score 0):

Can't really comment on #1, but for #2, can you try attaching jvisualvm to see what's going on there? (and create a thread-dump and post it somewhere so that I can take a look at it).

I'd ask you to create a bug-report for that, but the new tracker is still not up (I hope I'm able to put it up right after the funding at http://igg.me/at/liclipse is finished).

Comment: Hi Fabio, #2 I solved by reinstalling eclipse from scratch and added all my requirements. However, #1 still delays the startup procedure. I'll try the jvisualvm to see what's happening during #1, but I guess it's related to the JRE version. Happens on my 15"MB Retina, not on my 13"MBPro'12.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by following these steps. They essentially disable one 
JRE.http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559?viewlocale=en_US